# perl: Stripping leading zero in alphanumeric string

Tags: regex, perl

How to strip all leading zeros of an alphanumeric string in `Perl`?

For example:

```
"03ABCDE" --> "3ABCDE";

"30ABCDE0123"--> "30ABCDE123";

"30XY09ZZZ0001" --> "30XY9ZZZ1"
```

EDIT: John Doe pointed out the correct direction for solving this problem, and I made this code to solve this problem. Thanks!

```
$i =~s /0{1,}(?=[1-9])//g;
```

Comment: You have to be more specific. _Leading zeroes_ implies at the beginning of a string. It looks like that's not what you want.

Comment: you need to use a look-ahead regex to check if the following character is a number, different than 0

Comment: Firstly, it looks you don't want to remove "leading zeroes", you want to remove "leading zeroes and zeroes that immediately follow a letter". Is that accurate? Secondly, StackOverflow is not here to write code for you. It is here to help you fix problems in your code. Please show us what you already have. If you don't already have any code, then you don't want StackOverflow, you want to pay a programmer.

Comment: Most of [your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5179776/nissa?tab=questions) have good answers, but only one was accepted. Please go back through your questions and accept answers that solved your problems.

Comment: @DaveCross you are wrong, he wants to remove the zero's followed by a number

Comment: @JohnDoe: We don't know what he wants. Your description and mine both match all of his examples. But until he clarifies, we're just guessing.

Comment: What I means is "leading zeros in all numbers" within a string. 09, 30, 0123,etc. are all numbers in the string. Well, previously I think leading zero only apply to "numbers", not the whole string, but I get the correct meaning now. Also, I cannot give any codes, although I know some perl and regex, I never heard of lookahead regex, so I just don't know where to start. @John Doe 's reply is a good one, as he pointed out where should I look into, but Dave Cross 's reply is a bad and unfriendly one.

Anyway, I've looked into lookahead regex, and made the code successfully. So, problem solved!

Comment: What about `A1005B`? The solution you have would strip the two zeroes right out and you'd have `A15B`. Is that an expected result? Also, please post your own solution as an answer for future readers.

Comment: `{1,}` is more simply just `+`

Comment: @Nissa: You should post your solution as an answer and then accept it. I'm sorry that you thought my comment was unfriendly, but I was just explaining how StackOverflow works.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a lookbehind to match zeroes that are preceded by non-digits. In addition to that, you also need to match real leading zeroes at the beginning of the string.

```
my @strings = qw(03ABCDE 30ABCDE0123 30XY09ZZZ0001);
foreach (@strings) {
    print "$_ --> ";
    s/^0+|(?<=\D)0+//g;
    print "$_\n";
}
```

See https://regex101.com/r/xF7uM9/1 for a match demo.